# Import buildscripts in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am pretty new with gradle, I want to include a plugin globally, and I don't know how.
In my project(wish I DO NOT OWN), there are multiple build.gradle, and there is a commons.gradle folder. In there is created a script like this
**myscript.gradle**

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.13.1"
        }
    }
```

Then in of the build.gradle I have this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    apply from: "$path-to/myscript.gradle", to: buildscript
}
apply plugin: "com.github.hierynomus.license"
```

but I keep getting a Plugin with id com.github.hierynomus.license" not found. I am using Gradle 3.1. any help or hint would greatly help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by doing the following:

**myScript.gradle**

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.13.1"
        }
    }
```

then in the **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    apply from: "$path-to/myScript.gradle", to: buildscript
}
plugins{id "com.github.hierynomus.license" version "0.13.1"}
apply plugin: "com.github.hierynomus.license"
```

I was not able to find anything online, so I hope this will help someone one day.

ps: Sorry for my bad English